# Is there any way to build opencv-2.4.10 contrib module only?

Tags: android, opencv

I am building android application which requires face recognition feature of opencv. I am statically placing all the opencv .so files in lib folder, opencv is taking to much memory(more than 22 MB), so is there any way to build only contrib module of the opencv.

Comment: you can skip some. but you will at least need core,highgui,imgproc

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you explain the procedures to do the same